# Can I use Async inside Dart Isolate ??? its not working

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, nullable, dart-isolates

I am using ImageEditor package to merge different images. below is my code. its working perfectly fine without using Isolate, when i use it with isolate, i get null error.

**Working code without Isolate**

```dart
startEditing() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < image1.length || i == 0; i++) {
    if (image1.isNotEmpty) {
      img1 = await File(image1[i].path).readAsBytes();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < image2.length || i == 0; i++) {
      if (image2.isNotEmpty) {
        img2 = await File(image2[i].path).readAsBytes();
      }
      final ImageEditorOption optionGroup = ImageEditorOption();
      optionGroup.outputFormat = const OutputFormat.png(100);
      optionGroup.addOptions([
        MixImageOption(
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: 1000,
          height: 1000,
          target: MemoryImageSource(img1),
        ),
        MixImageOption(
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: 1000,
          height: 1000,
          target: MemoryImageSource(img2),
        ),
      ]);

      try {
      final Uint8List? result = await ImageEditor.editImage(
                    image: mainImg, imageEditorOption: optionGroup);
                if (result == null) {
                  image = null;
                } else {
                  await saveImage(result, index);
                  setState(() {
                    image = MemoryImage(result);
                    index++;
                  });
                }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Code with Isolate not working**

```dart
startEditing(SendPort sendPort) async {
  for (var i = 0; i < image1.length || i == 0; i++) {
    if (image1.isNotEmpty) {
      img1 = await File(image1[i].path).readAsBytes();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < image2.length || i == 0; i++) {
      if (image2.isNotEmpty) {
        img2 = await File(image2[i].path).readAsBytes();
      }
      final ImageEditorOption optionGroup = ImageEditorOption();
      optionGroup.outputFormat = const OutputFormat.png(100);
      optionGroup.addOptions([
        MixImageOption(
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: 1000,
          height: 1000,
          target: MemoryImageSource(img1),
        ),
        MixImageOption(
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: 1000,
          height: 1000,
          target: MemoryImageSource(img2),
        ),
      ]);

      try {
        final Uint8List? result = await ImageEditor.editImage(
            image: mainImg, imageEditorOption: optionGroup);
        if (result == null) {
          image = null;
        } else {
          await saveImage(result, index);

          image = MemoryImage(result);
          index++;
          sendPort.send(image);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**saveImage method**

```dart
Future<String> saveImage(Uint8List bytes, int i) async {
  final name = '${filenames[i]}';
  final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(bytes, name: name);
  print(result);

  return result['filePath'];
}
```

**Receiving in main thread**

```dart
  getImageas() async {
    ReceivePort receiverPort =
        ReceivePort(); 
    final isolate =
        await Isolate.spawn(startEditing, receiverPort.sendPort);
    receiverPort.listen((data) {
      print('Receiving: ' + data + ', ');
    });
  }
```

I get this error:

```
I/flutter (21937): Null check operator used on a null value
```

in this line:

```
 final Uint8List? result = await ImageEditor.editImage(
            image: mainImg, imageEditorOption: optionGroup);
```

**I am sure that img1, img2, mainImg, image1, image2 values are not null... check 1000 times. I have also used flutter compute, and same result.**

Answer (score 1):

Flutter plugins that call into native code (such as `image_editor`) do not work in isolates spawned by `Isolate.spawn`.

The [`flutter_isolate`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) package spawns isolates from native code for this reason.  You should be able to use it to call `image_editor` in an isolate.  (Disclaimer: I've never used `flutter_isolate`.)

Comment: yeah, its working but only once. it saves 1 image and stops.  no errors.